# C++ class member behaving as local variable

Tags: c++, string, class, oop

I have just started programming in C++, and I have found an awkward issue. Basically:

- I have one class where a member is a `char[MAX_LEN]` containing the full path of a file.
- I have one (`char*`) that points to the name (without the full path) of the file.

When I constructed this class, I found that the (`char*`) pointer is actually pointing to a local variable inside the constructor, obtaining wrong results.

Precisely, the class is:

```
class File_t{
  public:
    char        fullPath[1024];
    char*            name;

File_t(){};  // Default constructor
File_t(const char* fullPath_){
  /*  Copy the input name on fullPath   */
  strncpy(fullPath, fullPath_, sizeof(fullPath));

  /* Auxiliary variable to remove the path */
  char* auxstr=fullPath;
  name = auxstr;

  /* Loop to remove the path  */
  while(1){ 
      auxstr = strstr(auxstr,"/");
      if(auxstr){auxstr=auxstr+1; name=auxstr;}
      else{break;}
  }
}
};
```

And, for instance, the main consists in creating several instances of "File_t" and fill with several files /some/path/foo1,2,...

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  const int N = 3;
  File_t CC[N];
  char fileName[100];

  for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    sprintf(fileName,"%s%d","some/path/foo",i);
    CC[i] = File_t(&fileName[0]);
  }


  cout << "Summary" << endl;
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) cout << "File " << CC[i].name << " in " << CC[i].fullPath << endl;


  return 0;
}
```

The program output is:

```
File foo2 in some/path/foo0
File foo2 in some/path/foo1
File foo2 in some/path/foo2
```

That is, the name points to some local variable to the constructor. I have this problem with Apple, GNU, and Intel compilers.

PS: I know I should avoid using C-style strings in C++, but this was just made to learn C++ basics.

Comment: Never use `strncpy`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried strcpy and the problem persists. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Instead of use `strstr()`, use `strrchr()` — find the rightmost occurrence of a character (instead of a 1-character string).  Note that you might need to worry about `"/abc/def/ghi//"` with trailing slashes (with `strrchr()` or `strstr()`).  In general, though, it appears that you've found one of the reasons why people recommend not using C-style strings in C++; they're easily misused.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on finding the file name. However, I believe this could also happen with arrays of integers or doubles. I mean, I thought this should work.

Comment: As usual for classes containing pointers, the problem is in not adhering to Rule of 3.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot There's no rule of 3 issue, they just havent implemented copy constructor or assignment operator. This is actually one of the rare times that the rule of 3 doesnt even apply: you don't need a destructor.

Comment: Your default constructor should leave your class in a coherent state.  It might be better written as: `File_t() { name = fullPath; *name = '\0'; }` for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is a broken assignment operator (and copy constructor). In this line:

```
CC[i] = File_t(&fileName[0]);
```

you construct a temporary `File_t` object, then assign it to `CC[i]`. `fullPath` is an array, so all elements are copied. This is fine. But `name` is a pointer, so the only thing that's copied is the pointer itself. This is a problem because it still points into the `fullPath` of the temporary object.

At the end of this statement, the temporary object is destroyed. Now `CC[i].name` is an invalid pointer.

To fix this, define an appropriate assignment operator. It might do something like:

```
strcpy(fullPath, other.fullPath);
name = fullPath + (other.name - other.fullPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Melpomene had the answer. The copy procedure was not indicated, and pointers were pointing to local variables.

If the copy procedure is added (following his advice):

```
File_t& operator=(const File_t& other)
{
    strcpy(fullPath, other.fullPath);
    name = &fullPath[0] + (other.name - &other.fullPath[0]);
    return *this;
}
```

then the program works.

Thanks everyone for the answers!